# Check rendered SQL sent to the server from SSDT/SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, sql-server-data-tools, db2-luw

I'm building a report in Visual Studio Data Tools and I'm having trouble in passing a multivalued parameter to a DB2 LUW server.

How to check the rendered SQL string sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017) to see the actual query. Or you can catch it in the query monitor in SSMS.

If you post more details someone might be able to see what's wrong. It usually has to do with how the `WHERE` clause is written.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto did you get a chance to try this out? If it helped, please mark this as answered.